# Using TexStudio with unicode - incorrect cursor position

Tags: texstudio, unicode

I find myself becoming a fan of using more and more unicode as it make source files way more readable. In my favourite editor TexStudio I am facing a slight annoyance: some unicode characters are considered as a single column and others as multiple columns which prevents proper block selection. Also, the characters do not appear as mono-spaced despite selecting a mono-spaced font (Deja-Vu Sans Mono).

Here is what happens when I try to make a block selection: ℂ is considered as a single column and the other blackboard bold characters are considered as 2 columns:

[image]

1. Is there a way for me to fix the wrong column issue, or is that a TexStudio bug? (I think it likely originates from  using more bytes than ℂ in unicode, as the characters come from different blocks.)
2. I noticed that the unicode characters have varying width - despite using a monospaced font for the editor. Is there a **true** monospaced font for math related unicode?

Comment: (technically saying "using more bytes in Unicode" is incorrect, but it's likely it's because it takes more bytes in UTF16 in this case.

Comment: For question 2, there's always Unifont, but it's ugly.

Comment: Ask here https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues the devs answer pretty quickly.

Comment: Which version of TeXstudio are you using? There are indeed some issues with [multicursor behavior](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/2296).